# jqueryui connected sortable list to activate hover when dragged

Tags: css, jquery-ui

**In Short**

I need to be able to activate a menu on hover while I'm dragging a sortable object.  Is this possible?

**The context:**

I have a nav menu that's being powered by cssmenu, which basically takes list items and arranges them into a nice clean menu structure. I'd like to connect the lists in the nav menu and be able to rearrange the elements with jqueryui sortable connected lists. I can get the connected lists to work separately (outside of the cssmenu) and within one menu of a particular list. The problem is when I try to drag from one menu item to another, the drop-down isn't activated.

You can see in this fiddle that I can sort objects within a list but I can't activate the drop-down menu to drag it into another list (i.e. drag from the yellow list to the blue list or vice versa):

http://jsfiddle.net/9j5wyoLn/

html

```
<div id='cssmenu'>
    <ul id='subNavElements'>
    <li class='active has-sub'><a href='#'><span>About Us</span></a>
        <ul id="sortable1" class="connectedSortable">
          <li class="">Item 1</li>
          <li class="">Item 2</li>
          <li class="">Item 3</li>
          <li class="">Item 4</li>
        </ul>
    </li>   
    <li class='active has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Articles</span></a>
        <ul id="sortable2" class="connectedSortable">
          <li class="">Article 1</li>
          <li class="">Article 2</li>
          <li class="">Article 3</li>
          <li class="">Article 4</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

js

```
//make sortable
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( "#sortable1, #sortable2" ).sortable({
      connectWith: ".connectedSortable"
    }).disableSelection();

  });
```

css: handled in fiddle (too much to show below)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out...

I added a class in the css called "openSaysMe" which styles the elements to appear.

```
    #cssmenu .openSaysMe {
      left: auto;
      top: 34px;
      opacity: 1;
    }
```

Then I added the class when the items are being sorted, took the class away once the sorting was complete.

```
$( "#sortable1, #sortable2, #sortable3" ).sortable({
      connectWith: ".connectedSortable",
      sort: function( event, ui ) {
        $('#cssmenu ul ul').addClass('openSaysMe');
      },
      beforeStop: function( event, ui ) {
        $('#cssmenu ul ul').removeClass('openSaysMe');
      }
    }).disableSelection();
```

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9j5wyoLn/2/